# Encrypting communication in Eneter between single server and multiple clients, each using different key

Tags: java, c#, encryption

With [Eneter](http://www.eneter.net/) it is possible to set custom serializer in `DuplexTypedMessagesFactory`, which could be used for encrypting communication between client and server.

```
DuplexTypedMessagesFactory sender_factory = new DuplexTypedMessagesFactory();
sender_factory.setSerializer(new EncryptingSerializer(client_private_key, server_public_key));
sender_ = sender_factory.createDuplexTypedMessageSender(MyResponse.class, MyRequest.class);
```

In my app I have single server and multiple clients, but obviously each channel should be encrypted individually using its own keys (or relevant RSA key pairs). Unfortunately serializer interface does not expose any identifier of channel from which the message is coming:

```
public class EncryptingSerializer implements ISerializer {
    private RsaSerializer rsa_serializer_;

    public EncryptingSerializer(RSAPrivateKey priv, RSAPublicKey pub) {
        rsa_serializer_ = new RsaSerializer(pub, priv);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> Object serialize(T t, Class<T> aClass) throws Exception {
        return rsa_serializer_.serialize(t, aClass);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T deserialize(Object o, Class<T> aClass) throws Exception {
        return rsa_serializer_.deserialize(o, aClass);
    }
}
```

so above code is ok for client side (it seems I can even delay initialization of `rsa_serializer_` until after connection is established, so e.g. server public key is fetched during authentication / pairing process). However for server side the same serializer object needs to serve multiple communication channels, but each needs a different `rsa_serializer_` object.

Is there any way around this or do I just need to push encryption into the higher level (sending and receiving simple `BlobRequest` / `BlobResponse` objects, whose content would be encrypted before passing to framework and decrypt after getting from framework)?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up re-implementing DuplexTypedMessageReceiver on top of DuplexStringMessageReceiver fetching and storing appropriate serializer on demand from outside:

```
class EncryptingTypedMessageReceiver<TResponse, TRequest> : IDuplexTypedMessageReceiver<TResponse, TRequest> {
  public event EventHandler<TypedRequestReceivedEventArgs<TRequest>> MessageReceived;
  public event EventHandler<ResponseReceiverEventArgs> ResponseReceiverConnected;
  public event EventHandler<ResponseReceiverEventArgs> ResponseReceiverDisconnected;

  private IDuplexStringMessageReceiver string_receiver_;
  private Func<string, ISerializer> serializer_factory_;
  private Dictionary<string, ISerializer> serializers_by_receiver_id_ = new Dictionary<string, ISerializer>();

  public EncryptingTypedMessageReceiver(IDuplexStringMessageReceiver receiver, Func<string, ISerializer> serializer_factory) {
    serializer_factory_ = serializer_factory;
    string_receiver_ = receiver;
    string_receiver_.RequestReceived += OnRequestReceived;
    string_receiver_.ResponseReceiverConnected += OnResponseReceiverConnected;
    string_receiver_.ResponseReceiverDisconnected += OnResponseReceiverDisconnected;
  }

  private void OnRequestReceived(object sender, StringRequestReceivedEventArgs e) {
    TRequest typedRequest = serializers_by_receiver_id_[e.ResponseReceiverId].Deserialize<TRequest>(e.RequestMessage);
    var typedE = new TypedRequestReceivedEventArgs<TRequest>(e.ResponseReceiverId, e.SenderAddress, typedRequest);
    if (MessageReceived != null) {
      MessageReceived(sender, typedE);
    }
  }

  public void SendResponseMessage(string responseReceiverId, TResponse responseMessage) {
    string stringMessage = (string)serializers_by_receiver_id_[responseReceiverId].Serialize(responseMessage);
    string_receiver_.SendResponseMessage(responseReceiverId, stringMessage);
  }

  private void OnResponseReceiverConnected(object sender, ResponseReceiverEventArgs e) {
    if (ResponseReceiverConnected != null)
      ResponseReceiverConnected(sender, e);
    serializers_by_receiver_id_.Add(e.ResponseReceiverId, serializer_factory_(e.ResponseReceiverId));
  }

  private void OnResponseReceiverDisconnected(object sender, ResponseReceiverEventArgs e) {
    if (ResponseReceiverDisconnected != null)
      ResponseReceiverDisconnected(sender, e);
    serializers_by_receiver_id_.Remove(e.ResponseReceiverId);
  }

  public IDuplexInputChannel AttachedDuplexInputChannel {
    get {
      return string_receiver_.AttachedDuplexInputChannel;
    }
  }

  public bool IsDuplexInputChannelAttached {
    get {
      return string_receiver_.IsDuplexInputChannelAttached;
    }
  }

  public void AttachDuplexInputChannel(IDuplexInputChannel duplexInputChannel) {
    string_receiver_.AttachDuplexInputChannel(duplexInputChannel);
  }

  public void DetachDuplexInputChannel() {
    string_receiver_.DetachDuplexInputChannel();
  }
}
```